# Simple problem with lots of calculations (analytic geometry)

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, solution-verification, analytic-geometry

I have this problem. I solved it all by hand.
It is quite straightforward in general.

But the solution has a lot of calculations.
So I just want to verify the answers which I got.

We have four points in Euclidean 3D coordinate space
(given with their orthogonal coordinates).

$A(-1,2,3)$
$B(0,4,4)$
$C(2,0,2)$
$D(-1,3,2)$

$M$ is the midpoint of the segment $AB$

We need to find
a) the distance from point D to the plane ABC
b) $\tan \measuredangle ACM$

I get these answers

a)  $ 3 / \sqrt{5} $

b)  $ 2 / ( 3 \sqrt{5} ) $

I wonder if someone could verify these answers with some software or via some other means.

Comment: I stuck this into Geogebra (software) and I get exactly the same result that you get.

Comment: @Narlin OK, thank you for the confirmation